# How to declare TabPage objcet as an array in c#.net windows application?

Tags: c#-4.0

for (int i = 0; i < boxNum; i++) {

```
                TabPage dynamicTabPage = new TabPage();
                dynamicTabPage.Name = "dynamicTab";
                dynamicTabPage.Text = "Box" + (i + 1);
                dynamicTabPage.BackColor = Color.Gray;

                DataGridView gd = new DataGridView();
                gd.Name = "gdData";
                gd.Width = 500;
                gd.BackColor = Color.Gray;
                gd.AutoGenerateColumns = false;




                //------------Add grid header columns--------------

                gd.Columns.Add("slno", "SlNo");
                gd.Columns.Add("item", "Item");
                gd.Columns.Add("Qty", "Quantity");
                gd.Columns.Add("Price", "Price");


                dynamicTabPage.Controls.Add(gd);
                this.tbAddItem.TabPages.Add(dynamicTabPage);
                gd.EditMode = DataGridViewEditMode.EditOnKeystroke;
           }
```

i want to declate tabpage object as an array.Inorder to access each tabpage controls separately.is there any other solution for getting the value of dynamic datagridview controls in each dynamic tabpage.

Comment: The TabControl.TabPages property is already a collection and behaves like an array, you can index it with the [] operator.  Pretty unclear why you'd want to duplicate it into an array, you'd just add risk by having a stale collection.  Also hard to see how it makes the snippet any better.  Otherwise not hard to do, Linq makes it a one-liner: var pages = dynamicTabPage.TabPages.OfType<TabPage>().ToArray();

Comment: TabPages of the tab control is dynamically added in the button click event.The number of TabPages is varies depend on particular value in the form. Each dynamically added tabPage contain dynamically added datagridview. I wanted to access each datagridview value present in each tab page and save it to the database.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem